# Find the derivate of a sqrt with two methods

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I'm a bit confused when it comes to finding the derivate of a function, of course using the definition gives me the right answer. But using the fast mechanism gives me a wrong answer or a least not the same as using the formal definiton:

$f(x)=\sqrt{4x-3}$

\begin{align*}
 f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}} && y=\sqrt{x} \therefore \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\\
 f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{\sqrt{4x-3}-(\sqrt{4x-3})}{h}} && f'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}\sqrt{4x-3} \\
 &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{{\sqrt{4(x+h)-3}-(\sqrt{4x-3})}}{h} && = (4x-3)^\frac{1}{2} \\
 &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{({\sqrt{4(x+h)-3})^2}-(\sqrt{4x-3})^2}{h({\sqrt{4(x+h)-3}+\sqrt{4x-3})}} && = \frac{1}{2}(4x-3)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} \\
 &=\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{4(x+h)-3-(4x-3)}{h({\sqrt{4(x+h)-3}+\sqrt{4x-3})}}} && = \frac{1}{2}\cdot{(4x-3)}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
 &=\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{4h}{h({\sqrt{4x+4h-3}+\sqrt{4x-3})}}} && = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{(4x-3)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \\
 &={\frac{4}{{\sqrt{4x-3}+\sqrt{4x-3}}}} && = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x-3}} \\
 &=\frac{4}{2\sqrt{4x-3}} && = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4x-3}} \\
\end{align*}

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{4x-3}} \neq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4x-3}}$

Comment: Your second method is flawed.  You fail to use the chain rule correctly.  It is also poorly written, as you have lines of the form $(4x-3)^{1/2}=\frac 12(4x-3)^{1/2-1}$ which, as an equality, is obviously false.

Comment: yeah, i wan't to know were the problem is that's way i'm asking

Comment: I told you.  You misapplied the chain rule.  The fact that $\frac d{dx} \sqrt x=\frac 1{2\sqrt x}$ does not imply that $\frac d{dx} \sqrt u=\frac 1{2\sqrt u}$ for some function $u=u(x)$.  Try $u(x)=4x$ for a counterexample.

Comment: @Carlos The chain rule says $(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. You forgot the $g'(x)$ that should produce a coefficient of $4$.